# Migrating multiple large solutions to PackageReference en masse

Tags: .net, nuget

My question is identical to [Nuget: Migrating multiple large Solutions to PackageReference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52272698/nuget-migrating-multiple-large-solutions-to-packagereference) which has an irrelevant answer.

So, how do we do it? I do not want to click each and every project amongst the hundreds we have.

Also, about Asp.Net projects - they do not support PackageReference, even if migrated manually? Or just the migration procedure from Microsoft does not support it?

Comment: For your question about ASP.NET, from the [PackageReference docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files): "ASP.NET apps targeting the full .NET Framework include only [limited support](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/5877) for PackageReference.".

Comment: That is a very useful tidbit. I am OK to leave asp.net as is. Still a hundred or two of regular class libraries to migrate.

Comment: Developed my own - https://github.com/MarkKharitonov/NuGetPCToPRMigrator Seems to work fine.

Comment: It's great that you developed a solution. Please post an actual answer, not just a link to your GitHub project, on the question you state this is a duplicate of. I expect such an answer would be quite useful to future visitors.

Comment: OK - https://stackoverflow.com/a/64200862/80002